# Why does image height get so large in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I'm calculating image height serverside to serve dynamic images but every once in a while the height in HTML becomes way too large:

`<div class="item_image" style="height: 1116px">`

Why is it so much as 1116px when the pics that a server with `get_serving_url` actually are not 1116px so I'm probably making some mistake in my algorithm:

```
class NewAdHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get_ad(self, key):
        data = memcache.get(key)
        if data is not None:
            return data
        else:
            data = Ad.get_by_id(long(key))
            memcache.add(key, data, 6000)
            return data

    def get_image(self, ad):
        data = memcache.get(str(ad.key()))
        if data is not None:
            return data
        else:
            data = ad.matched_images.get()
            memcache.add(str(ad.key()), data, 6000)
            return data

    def get_images(self, ad):
        data = memcache.get(str(ad.key()) + 'images')
        if data is not None:
            return data
        else:
            data = ad.matched_images
            memcache.add(str(ad.key()) + 'images', data, 6000)
            return data

    def get(self, id, html):
        logging.debug('logged in %s', self.logged_in)
        region = None
        city = None
        ad = self.get_ad(id)
        if not ad or not ad.published:
            self.error(404)
            return
        image = self.get_image(ad)
        thumb_url = None
        height = None#image.get_height()
        #logging.debug('height %d', height)
        maxheight = 80

        if image:
            img = images.Image(blob_key=str(image.primary_image.key()))
            img.im_feeling_lucky()
            img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
            height = img.height
            if height < 640: maxheight = height


        logging.debug('height %d', height)

        image_url = None
        country = ''
        if self.request.host.find('koolbusiness.com') > -1: country = 'India'
        elif self.request.host.find('montao.com') > -1: country = 'Brasil'
        elif self.request.host.find('hipheap.com') > -1: country = 'USA'
        if image:
            if image.primary_image:
                try:
                    image_url = \
                        images.get_serving_url(str(image.primary_image.key()),
                            size=640)
                    thumb_url = \
                        images.get_serving_url(str(image.primary_image.key()),
                            size=120)
                except Exception, e:
                    image_url = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                        + '_small.jpg'
            else:
                image_url = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                    + '_small.jpg'
        imv = []
        for i in self.get_images(ad):
            img = images.Image(blob_key=str(i.primary_image.key()))

            img.im_feeling_lucky()
            img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
            #maxheight = img.height
            #if img.height < 640: maxheight = 640
            if img.height > maxheight: maxheight = img.height
            if i.primary_image:
                try:
                    i1 = \
                        images.get_serving_url(str(i.primary_image.key()))
                    imv.append(i1)
                except Exception, e:
                    i1 = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                        + '_small.jpg'
                    imv.append(i1)
        price = ad.price
        if ad.geopt and not ad.city:
            logging.info('geopt:' + str(ad.geopt))
            url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json' \
                + '?latlng={},{}&sensor=false'.format(ad.geopt.lat,
                    ad.geopt.lon)
            result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
            jsondata = json.loads(result.content)

            for result in jsondata['results']:
                for component in result['address_components']:
                    if 'administrative_area_level_1' \
                        in component['types']:
                        region = component['long_name'].replace('County'
                                , '')
                    if 'locality' in component['types']:
                        city = component['long_name']

            if ad.city != city:
                ad.city = city
                ad.put()

            if ad.region != region:
                ad.region = region
                ad.put()

            if ad.price:  # and doesn't contain separators
                try:
                    price = \
                        i18n.I18n(self.request).format_decimal(int(ad.price))
                except Exception, e:
                    price = ad.price
        else:
            city = ad.city
            region = ad.region  # if ad.region eller get region

        if region == None:
            region = ''

        if region == None:
            region = ''
        regionentity = montaomodel.Region.all().filter('name =',
                region).get()
        cityentity = montaomodel.City.all().filter('name =', city).get()
        logging.debug('is logged in: %s', self.logged_in,)
        self.render_jinja(
            'view_ad',
            image_url=image_url,loggedin=self.logged_in,                 user= self.current_user,
           country = country,
            region=ad.region,
            regionentity=regionentity,
            cityentity=cityentity,
            city=city,
            imv=imv,request=self.request,   
            len=len(imv),height=maxheight,
            ad=ad,thumb_url=thumb_url,
            price=price,VERSION=VERSION,
            #user_url=(users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else None),
            admin=users.is_current_user_admin(),
            linebreak_txt=(ad.text.replace('\n', '<br>'
                           ) if ad.text else None),
            image=image,
            logged_in = self.logged_in,
            form=AddAdCityForm(),
            form_url=self.request.url,
            )
```

The code in the template is

```
 {% if image_url %} 

        <!-- Main Images -->    <div class="item_image" style="height: {{height}}px">

            <div class="item_arrow_left" style="height: 428px">             <i class="sprite_vi_arrow_left" style="margin-top: 200px"></i>      </div>      <div class="image_container">       <img src="{{image_url}}" id="main_image_0" alt="{{ad.title}}" title="Click for next image">             {% for im in imv %}     <img src="{{im}}" class="hidden" id="main_image_{{loop.index}}" alt="{{ad.title}}" class="thumb_image_single" title="Click for next image">
            {% endfor %}
```

Can you tell me what I can do about the problem? A live view of the problem is [here](http://www.koolbusiness.com/vi/7467183.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to specify height:1116px...height:auto should take care of what you need right?

Thanks
AB