# How to solve that image height gets too large for my dynamic views?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-app-engine, python-2.x

Background:
[Why does image height get so large in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338616/why-does-image-height-get-so-large-in-this-example)
The problem reappeared even though I applied the fix from the question:
[image]

Do you think the problem is in the presentation layer or serverside? I suppose I could make a fiddle with the problem but there are a lot of components and there might be a super easy solution to this, which it appeared to be just setting the image height to `auto` but it apppears to not work. Can you advice on what measures to take? The HTML is

```
<!-- Main Images -->
    <div class="item_image" style="height:auto">


            <div class="item_arrow_left" style="height: 428px">
            <i class="sprite_vi_arrow_left" style="margin-top: 200px"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="image_container">

    <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/v9WiErUPsBsOtHk9cKnA_ag3glBmZ9QG1D0wGC0DrUCgAJmyasVGt6njzCK2yUX4YjVa8TTeP8h8EmuCXlEgltt0R5g=s640" id="main_image_0" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" title="Click for next image">

    <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/v9WiErUPsBsOtHk9cKnA_ag3glBmZ9QG1D0wGC0DrUCgAJmyasVGt6njzCK2yUX4YjVa8TTeP8h8EmuCXlEgltt0R5g" class="hidden" id="main_image_1" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" class="thumb_image_single" title="Click for next image">


    <img src="http://lh4.ggpht.com/Y2IUX7VAMmxVGlf2B-3Y3TlKZ_GqgpqIX6HpyYDp3dwrI9N3Lf3QZrjGHEKhVybMxn6ke5xLVjkwBkg1frdJihxt" class="hidden" id="main_image_2" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" class="thumb_image_single" title="Click for next image">


    <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/CyuBJ4J3-CzndvoJ3q59tz29LLbME9awV4xMuiFVOm6FedTlt-uEzFBnQ5hWrPpbUagtdticpeuyxVhH_T2duiev2Q" class="hidden" id="main_image_3" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" class="thumb_image_single" title="Click for next image">



        </div>
        <div class="item_arrow_right" style="height: 428px">
            <i class="sprite_vi_arrow_right" style="margin-top: 200px"></i>
        </div>


    </div>


    <!-- Image Thumbnails -->
        <div class="item_img">
            <ul class="inlined"><!--
                <li><img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/v9WiErUPsBsOtHk9cKnA_ag3glBmZ9QG1D0wGC0DrUCgAJmyasVGt6njzCK2yUX4YjVa8TTeP8h8EmuCXlEgltt0R5g=s120" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" id="thumb_image_0" class="current  hoverable thumb_image"></li>-->

                <li><img  src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/v9WiErUPsBsOtHk9cKnA_ag3glBmZ9QG1D0wGC0DrUCgAJmyasVGt6njzCK2yUX4YjVa8TTeP8h8EmuCXlEgltt0R5g=s120" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" id="thumb_image_1"  class=" hoverable thumb_image"></li>

                <li><img  src="http://lh4.ggpht.com/Y2IUX7VAMmxVGlf2B-3Y3TlKZ_GqgpqIX6HpyYDp3dwrI9N3Lf3QZrjGHEKhVybMxn6ke5xLVjkwBkg1frdJihxt=s120" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" id="thumb_image_2"  class=" hoverable thumb_image"></li>

                <li><img  src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/CyuBJ4J3-CzndvoJ3q59tz29LLbME9awV4xMuiFVOm6FedTlt-uEzFBnQ5hWrPpbUagtdticpeuyxVhH_T2duiev2Q=s120" alt="Premium Food United Kingdom"Waleed Babar Khan" id="thumb_image_3"  class=" hoverable thumb_image"></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

A live view of the example is [here](http://www.koolbusiness.com/vi/7698187.html) and an example where it's working, which is most often, is [here](http://www.koolbusiness.com/vi/7751183.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `item_arrow_left` and `item_arrow_right` getting inline height from some script that why it gets that height the image have the correct height

this script line may help you

```
$('[class^="item_arrow_"]').css('height','auto');
```

Comment: It worked! But not with this script, it worked when I changed the HTML to `<div class="item_arrow_right" style="height:auto">` Thanks!